# Can I sufficiently secure an admin portal by only allowing connections from localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, architecture, phoenix-framework

Can I sufficiently protect API resources by only allowing access to those whose IP is `127.0.0.1`? This is of course assuming that the server on which the API resides is protected by strong password and key file.

Comment: I think this is primarily opinion based question. "Sufficient protection" depends of your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Some more context would be useful, as @quinz commented, but here are a few common web application issues that could affect you even if an attacker doesn't get a shell on your server:

- A [Server-Side Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Server_Side_Request_Forgery) attack could be used to cause the server to make requests on behalf of an attacker. These requests would originate from `localhost`. Depending on the specific vulnerability and admin API endpoints, such an attack could be used to exfiltrate data or make state-changing requests.
- Assuming an administrator sometimes uses a browser on the server (perhaps to access an admin interface), a [Cross-Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) attack could be used to make state-changing requests to the admin API. Normally CSRF requires the victim to be logged in to the application, but that doesn't apply here: they just need to be browsing websites from `localhost`.
- Similarly, a [Cross-Site Scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) attack could be used to force an administrator browsing from `localhost` to make requests to the API service. This assumes there's a web application component and not just a REST API, for example.